# determining if .htaccess is working

Tags: apache-2.2, permissions, .htaccess

Following some guide on the web, I have created the following .htaccess for my WordPress installation:

```
# protect the htaccess file
<files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>

# protect wpconfig.php
<files wp-config.php>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>
```

plus `chmod wp-config.php 600 and .htaccess 644`.

Which is the simplest way I can test if it is working properly? In case, I can create some other files to verify the work. I only want to be sure.

Comment: Programming questions should be asked on Stackoverflow. Server questions should be asked on Serverfault. I'm not sure which this is, but it's not a Superuser question.

Comment: Actually @Josh, home server administration is typically accepted on SU.  SF is geared towards IT pros who manage servers in a professional capacity.

Comment: I thought that any file starting with ".ht" (like .htaccess or .htpasswd) was hidden by default with Apache (but I could be wrong).

Comment: Still think that you might get better results on SF.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test this from outside your network - as if you are a normal person across the internet, you can try using a proxy server such as [Hidemyass](http://www.hidemyass.com) or [Proxify](http://www.proxify.com).

Answer (score 1):

To test if the directives are working, just try browsing to the files:

```
http://yoursite.com/wp-site/.htaccess
http://yoursite.com/wp-site/wp-config.php
```

When accessing the files you should get an error page.  Try removing the directives and test again, see that a valid page will load.-